# atom cannot start because libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 is not found, but ldd can locate it

Tags: debian, software-installation, crunchbang, shared-library

I've installed Atom editor on my Crunchbang VM. Atom depends on libc6>=2.15, but the stable Waldorf has libc6 2.13, so I had to set up dynamic linking as described [here](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/2020#issuecomment-48904370)

After that, I get another issue trying to run atom:

```
andrey@crunchbang:~$ atom
andrey@crunchbang:~$ /usr/share/atom/atom: error while loading shared libraries: 
libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

,which is strange, because the library is there and ldd can find it too:

```
andrey@crunchbang:~$ locate libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0.2400.10
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0.2400.10
andrey@crunchbang:~$ ldd /usr/share/atom/atom 
...
libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fef7aba6000)
libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fef7a8f3000)
...
```

There is plenty of similar questions on the web, but most of them were solved by installing `libgtk` (which I already have). I have also checked that symbolic link `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0` correctly points to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0.2400.10`, and even installed `i386` version which seemed to help some people with their programs. Nothing helped so far.

By the way, when I simply upgraded libc6 from the testing branch, I was able to run Atom right away without problems. However, the upgrade also broke my locale program and who knows what else, so I don't want to go the unstable way anymore.

Comment: Please post the output of `strace atom`.